# 3D Touch shortcuts - Color Icon

Tags: ios, shortcut, 3dtouch

I know how to develop 3D touch shortcuts with customized icon (grayscale) but my question is is there any possiblility to put colored image as a shortcut icon? I have tried a colored image with

```
UIApplicationShortcutIcon *logoIcon = [UIApplicationShortcutIcon iconWithTemplateImageName:@"field_valid"]
```

...but it won't appear. With a grayscale icon, it is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can but only with contact images.

See `UIApplicationShortcutIcon`:

> `init(contact: CNContact)`
>
> Creates a Home screen quick action icon
>   from the picture for a contact if available, or else creates a
>   monogram from the contact name.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationshortcuticon

Answer (score 1):

According to iOS Human Interface Guidelines, **this is not permitted.**

[From the Home Screen Actions section:](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/extensions/home-screen-actions/)

> Don't use an emoji in place of an icon. Emojis don't align properly with right-aligned text. Also, emojis are full color, **whereas quick action icons are monochromatic.**